# Regex keeps matching repeated numbers when I only want unique number

Tags: regex

I would like to match an exact number in a string, but my regex keeps matching the exact number if it repeats together.

I have the following string:

```
SomePrefix1201-21,4,52
```

And I have the following regex to find a match for 21:

```
SomePrefix[\d]+-[,\d]*21[,$]*
```

It will match this string fine.

However, it also matches:

```
SomePrefix1201-2121,4,52
```

But I only want it to match if it is the exact number.

The number may exist at the end too, so it is not always following by a comma.

I've been racking my brain like anything

**Update**

Based on the corrected answer below, I managed to find the exact regex I need, with one addition of a lookahead too.

```
SomePrefix[\d]+-([\d]*,)*21(?!\d)[,$]*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[,\d]*` part matches any number of digits and commas *in any order*. What you probably wanted was `([\d]*,)*` so that any preceding digits and commas must end in a comma (not a digit, which would become a part of the number).

Comment: The original regex recognizes any mixture of digits and commas, including the empty string. Your revised expression recognizes the empty string, and all mixtures of digits and commas which are *terminated* by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
SomePrefix[^-]+-(\d+,)*(21,|21$)
```

Match the prefix, followed by one or more non-dash characters, then a dash, then *zero or more comma-terminated digit fields*, followed either by `21,` (and possibly more material) or just `21` anchored to the end.

If the comma-terminated fields can be empty, then of course `\d*` rather than `\d+`.

It's not clear that you can widely use the anchor operator `$` inside a character class (perhaps some regex implementations have this feature), so I distributed it out into two matches for 21, which looks clear. The `21` can be factored out of this:

```
(21,|21$)  ->  21(,|$)
```